# Paypal Metchant API for VS2013 or Windows 8.1 Store Apps

Tags: c#, xaml, visual-studio-2013, paypal, windows-store-apps

I am trying to create Windows 8.1 Store Apps using Paypal Merchant API in Visual Studio 2013 update 2, but not able to add Paypal Merchant API using Visual Studio Nuget manager. Here is the link for [Paypal Merchant API](https://github.com/paypal/merchant-sdk-dotnet).

Comment: You need to use the windows 8 version of the sdk  https://github.com/paypal/Windows8SDK/

Comment: Yes, i used it, but its only for checkout, I need to interact with merchant API in windows store apps and windows phone apps.